# Pass an IEnumerable model to a controller via button MVC Net Core

Tags: parameter-passing, asp.net-core-mvc, ienumerable

I have a view where I have defined the model as:

```
@model IEnumerable <OnePortal.Models.Plant>
```

Within this view I have a button, which should pass the model to a controller according to:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportExcel", "Customer", new {gata = Model}, null)'">
```

As you can see, the action is called "ExportExcel" and the controller "Customer".

The action within the Customer controller looks like this:

```
public IActionResult ExportExcel(IEnumerable<Plant> gata){ 
}
```

However, when I debugg the controller, it says that the parameter passed (gata) has count=0, i.e. empty. I know that the model is not empty, since I later on in the view loop through the model and display its contents

Can anybody help me with this? Why is the model not passed properly?

***EDIT***

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Device(string id)
    {
        R2S.ServiceClient r2s = new R2S.ServiceClient();
        AnlData[] adData = r2s.GetAnlDataListAsync(new string[] { "STATION" }, new string[] { id }).Result; // lista med anläggningsdata 
        Apparat[] appData = r2s.GetApparaterAsync(new string[] {"STATION" }, new string[] { id }).Result; // lista med apparatdata

        var plants = PopulatePlantList(adData);//Skapar en lista över alla anläggningar
        var devices = PopulateDeviceList(appData);//Skapar en lista över alla apparater

        var viewModel = new PlantDeviceViewModel
        {
            Plants = plants,
            Devices = devices
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Comment: `gata` is going to be the string representation of `Model`, which if you inspect that isn't anywhere what you want. You need to figure out a way to serialize your model into something that will fit into a url. As a side note, if you have a button doing the work of an anchor then just use an anchor

Comment: Could you show the action method of first view? I would like to see how you get `IEnumerable <OnePortal.Models.Plant>`.

Comment: Hello @Win. I Just edited my post. Hope this answers you question.

Comment: Could you show ***Action method*** of first view?

Comment: Yes, sorry. There you go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the model not passed properly?

You ***cannot*** pass a complex model in URL query string. Even if you serialize it, URL has character limit.

Ideally you just want to pass ***Id***, then retrieve `plants` data again inside `ExportExcel` action method.

```
<button class="btn btn-info" type="button" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ExportExcel", "Customer", 
    new {id = ViewData["Id"]}, null)'">

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Device(string id)
{
   ...
   var viewModel = new PlantDeviceViewModel
   {
      Plants = plants,
      Devices = devices
   };
   ViewData["Id"] = id;
   return View(viewModel);
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ExportExcel(string id)
{
   R2S.ServiceClient r2s = new R2S.ServiceClient();
   Apparat[] appData = r2s.GetApparaterAsync(
       new string[] {"STATION" }, new string[] { id }).Result; // lista med apparatdata

   var plants = PopulatePlantList(adData);//Skapar en lista över alla 
   ...
}
```